# Regex pattern that supports account number with special character hyphen and after we should allow optional number pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am using:

```
Pattern.compile("^[0-9\w?]")
```

It should allow both: `12345678`, `12345678-00001`

Can you suggest a valid pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?$
```

Here is the [Online demo of above regex](https://regex101.com/r/JG6MpG/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^\d+   ##Checking if value starts from digits(1 or more occurrences) here.
(?:    ##Starting a non capturing group from here.
-\d+   ##Checking if it has -(hyphen) and followed by 1 or more digits.
)?$     ##Closing non capturing group here and keeping it optional to match OP's both cases at the end of the value.
```

Comment: But is it possible to add extenstion to : pattren.compile("^[0-9]*$"). THIS IS working for accountnumber validation .

Comment: I mean i need to change this existing pattren to allow  account nber like : 123456-00001  only

Comment: @ClayJensen, To only allow `123456-00001` try `^\d+-\d+$` once.